# Codyn - multivariate_change error. How to filter replicates with multiple species records?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am trying to use the package Codyn and the function multivariate_change() on my dataset (code and dataset sample posted below). I need to solve the multiple records error.

```
library(codyn)
multivariate_change(df, 
                    time.var="time", 
                    replicate.var = "replicate", 
                    species.var = "species", 
                    abundance.var = "abundance")


Error in check_single(df, species.var, time.var = time.var, replicate.var = replicate.var) : 
  Multiple records for one or more species found at:
 time   replicate
 "2.2017" "111"     
 "2.2013" "135"     
 "2.2014" "135"  etc.etc.

structure(list(replicate2 = c("2163", "2164", "2171", "2199", "2233", 
"2234", "2235", "236", "2426", "2427", "2430"), UKX = c("8145700", 
"8145700", "8143625", "1100925", "1100925", "1100925", "1100925", 
"8143625", "3315425", "3315425", "3418450"), Date = c(1189987200, 
1189987200, 1188950400, 1190246400, 1188259200, 1188259200, 1188345600, 
906336000, 1220400000, 1220400000, 1220313600), time = c(3.2007, 
3.2007, 3.2007, 3.2007, 2.2007, 2.2007, 2.2007, 3.1998, 3.2008, 
3.2008, 3.2008), replicate = c("234", "331", "57", "336", "336", 
"336", "342", "57", "356", "313", "157"), species = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), abundance = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Time2 = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 8, 8, 8, 
20, 26, 26, 26)), row.names = 100:110, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I fixed it thanks!

Comment: Note that R is case-sensitive, so if your column name is upper case, then you should use the same case

Comment: e.g. `multivariate_change(df, time.var = "Time", replicate.var = "Replicate", species.var = "species", abundance.var = "abundance")` based on the column name.  But, it is giving errors, may be due to example data is too small with `abundance' all 0s

Comment: solved by removing all the zero's from the overall data frame.